# Is it possible to use a @XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation to unmarshal a method's return value?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, cxf

Basically, I'm trying to implement JAXB's XML adapter pattern (@XmlJavaTypeAdapter) in order to transfer Map-style (key-value pair, no SOAP equivalent) objects between a CXF [Java] and .NET [Microsoft] solution (Using WSI Basic 1.1, doc/lit).

To do so, I followed [Martin Lansler's adapater example](http://eskatos.wordpress.com/2008/03/14/a-simple-map-wrapper-to-use-with-jaxb/). However, I'm trying to unmarshall my **Java method's return type** (i.e. MAP, see below). My 'XmlAdapter' class's '**unmarshal**' method is never called I get the exception in fig2.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
//From PriceService interface
//We want to unmarshal the 'Map<Integer, Double>' return type

@WebMethod(action="getPriceBreak")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=java.util.Map.class, value=WSMapAdapter.class)
public Map<Integer, Double>  getPriceBreak(@WebParam(name="productCode") String productCode) {
}

//Fig2
INFO: Interceptor has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"return"). Expected elements are (none) 
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:622)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:527)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:114)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.getPara(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:240)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:117)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:236)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:645)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:2132)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:2015)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1940)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:66)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:627)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:236)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:471)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:301)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:253)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:121)
at $Proxy36.getPriceBreak(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.doInvoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:416)
at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.doInvoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:392)
at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.invoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:379)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at $Proxy37.getPriceBreak(Unknown Source)
at fisher.insight.service.TestLocalWSPriceServiceII.testGetPriceBreak(TestLocalWSPriceServiceII.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
at org.springframework.test.ConditionalTestCase.runBare(ConditionalTestCase.java:76)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
```

Comment: I have a feeling that `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` is only applicable for properties in JAXB beans. Maybe package-level type adapter will work (via `package-info.java`) but I doubt.